# SAS macro for creating multiple proq sql tables. Error: numeric opperand required

Tags: sas, sas-macro

I have a list of IDs that contain multiple "XO codes". I want to create a macro that will loop through these IDs and create a table for each using a where statement that corresponds to the appropriate XO code. EX:

```
%let ID_77= '35X02','35X04';
%let DnO_IDs= &ID_77; /intends to add more &ID_ numbers/

%macro loop;
   proc sql;
      %do k=1 %to %sysfunc(countw(&DnO_IDs_Ids.));
         %let ID= %scan(&DnO_IDs.,&k.);
         create table EP_&ID as
         select * from table
         where XO in ("&ID.") and AY>=(&CurrY-14);
      %end;
   quit;
%mend;
%loop;
```

I am receiving this error:
ERROR: A character operand was found in the %EVAL function or %IF condition where a numeric operand is required. The condition was: 
       '35X04' 
ERROR: Argument 2 to macro function %SCAN is not a number.
ERROR: The macro LOOP will stop executing.

Comment: Your list of values has quotes. So when you scan the list you are getting the quotes into the macro variable.  So you are attempting to create a table named `EP_'35X02'`. You should either remove the quotes from the original list or remove them from the new `ID` macro variable.

Comment: What is `&DnO_IDs_Ids.` doing?  That's an extra `&ids` compared to what you have in your `%let` statement.

Answer (score 1):

The quotes are an issue and should not be needed. Using comma as your delimiter can also cause trouble. It would work better to use spaces.

```
%let ID_77= 35X02 35X04;
%let DnO_IDs= &ID_77; /intends to add more &ID_ numbers/
%let CurrY=2015;

%macro loop;
%local k id ;
   proc sql;
%do k=1 %to %sysfunc(countw(&DnO_IDs));
  %let ID= %scan(&DnO_IDs,&k);
     create table EP_&ID as 
       select * from table
       where XO in ("&ID") and AY>=(&CurrY-14)
     ;
%end;
  quit;
%mend;
%loop;
```

If you do want to use the values as quoted comma separated lists then you need to modify your `COUNTW()` and `%SCAN()` function calls appropriately and add a call to `DEQUOTE()` to remove the quotes.

```
%let ID_77= '35X02','35X04';

... %sysfunc(countw(%superq(DnO_IDs),%str(,)));
  %let ID= %sysfunc(dequote(%scan(%superq(DnO_IDs),&k,%str(,))));
```

Comment: I edited the code accordingly and am now receiving this error: ERROR: Invalid symbolic variable name '35X02','35X04'. These codes have been referenced in proc sql tables before with the comma separated and quoted format, so I don't understand why the variable name would now be invalid

Comment: It is difficult to tell without seeing the log.   You would not use `'35X02','35X04'` as the name of anything. It might be useful as part of a statement like `XO in ('35X02','35X04')`.  Perhaps the values are still macro quoted?  If you have applied macro quoting you might try using the `%unquote()` macro function to remove the macro quoting from the value so that the macro processor will pass the characters unquoted to the SAS language processor.

Comment: Just as an FYI, the best practice in SAS is to not do this.  There is rarely a need for splitting the data this way since BY group processing is quite efficient. Otherwise, here's a write up on several common ways to accomplish this task. http://www.sascommunity.org/wiki/Split_Data_into_Subsets

Answer (score 0):

I think this should resolve the issue: 
%do k=1 %to %eval(%sysfunc(countw(&DnO_IDs_Ids.)));

Might be %sysfunc return value is considered non integer.

Comment: SAS macro language has no concept of "integer" in terms of the macro variable.  This is exactly what the `%scan` function is doing internally, and is failing.

Comment: Yeah .. my bad. Automatically %EVAL will be added to %SCAN and %QSCAN. It is anyway redundant to add it again